# How to make multiple layered table form with R and shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Any one can help me create table like this (multiple layers)?

I have tried many different functions in **R** such as table, tapply, aggregate etc.
I can make the parts of the values, but do not know how to add the parts of the column and row names (gray part) ..

Suppose there are four variables : gender, grade, year, area.
With 4 factorial input variables, I would like to create this form of table with **R** and shiny.
The values in the table are just counts.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You mean make one by hand on paper?To type one into Word? Construct one in some package? There's not enough detail here to even know if this is on topic.

Comment: To help your future studies, note that the conventional spellings are _male_ and _female_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `ftable()` function is what you're looking for:

```
d <- data.frame(Year=sample(c("2007", "2014"), 775, replace=TRUE),
     Gender=sample(c("Mail", "Femail"), 775, replace=TRUE),
     Grade=sample(c("1st grad", "2nd grad", "3rd grad"), 775, replace=TRUE),
     Area=sample(c("City area", "Rural area"), 775, replace=TRUE),
     Income=1000*runif(775))

d1 <- ftable(d, row.vars=c("Year", "Area"), col.vars=c("Gender", "Grade"))
d1

#                 Gender   Femail                       Mail                  
#                 Grade  1st grad 2nd grad 3rd grad 1st grad 2nd grad 3rd grad
# Year Area                                                                   
# 2007 City area               27       32       37       37       30       37
#      Rural area              29       26       25       41       36       30
# 2014 City area               30       29       30       27       32       29
#      Rural area              35       36       42       31       35       32
```

If you want to display the mean income for each of the groups in the table, there are a number of options. One way is to use a combination of functions from the `plyr` and `reshape2` packages. There are probably better or more efficient ways, but this does the trick:

```
library(plyr)
d1 <- ddply(d, .(Year, Gender, Grade, Area), summarise,
      mean=mean(Income))

library(reshape2)
dcast(d1, Year+Area ~ Gender+Grade)
```

Comment: I really appreciate this good answer.  I have one more question. Is there a way to put sum (or mean) instead of count, while supposing there are another income variable?

Comment: @RayGold I hope this above edit answers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mat another problem. I wonder whether there is a way to visualize the table in a **r_shiny**. When I send 1*1 table, the results is fine. But for the 2*2 table, the result is just a white board.